# Setting up Django on web server with nginx and uWSGI

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

<del>I am following [this](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) guide in order to set up one Django app with nginx.</del>

I have installed Nginx and I can access it on `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.1:80`.

I have this configuration file:

```
upstream django {
    # connect to this socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 8000 default_server;
    listen [::]:8000 default_server;

    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    charset     utf-8;

    #Max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/dwv/Documents/FMQDjango/BetApp/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/dwv/Documents/FMQDjango/BetApp/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have symlinked this file to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

I still can access the "welcome message" on `127.0.0.1:80` but i cannot connect to `127.0.0.1:8000`.

I have a file called `porto.jpg` on my media folder, then I try to access it on `127.0.0.1:8000/media/porto.jpg` but i still cannot connect to server.

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

I don't even know why I was getting that error.

**What I was doing:**

- Create an empty file on my Project root folder;
- Edit the file on Sublime with the code I pasted on my question;
- ERROR. Do not work.

**What I did to solve it:**

- `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconf`;
- The previous command opens an editor;
- Write the same code on the terminal Editor;
- It worked!

The code is the same, I don't know why, on first approach it do not work.